# Update quantity with same column value name

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have this following data in my database table (Items):

[image]

Above image shows that row 1 and row 2 have same values.

My question is how can I delete the row 2, but because it detects it have same product name, it will add the quantity? For this example row 2 quantity will be added to row 1 quantity. So row 1 quantity have 20 rather than 10, and the database table have only just 1 row.

Sorry for not providing the code.

SQL INSERT Query for the above image:

```
INSERT INTO [Items] ([Category], [Name], [Quantity], [Price], [Label], [Status]) VALUES (@Category, @Name, @Quantity, @Price, @Label, @Status)
```

SQL SELECT Query for the above image:

```
SELECT [Category], [Name], [Quantity], [Price], [Label], [Status], [ImageData] FROM [Items] WHERE [Status] = @Active ORDER BY [Category] ASC;
```

The `@Active` Parameter is `Active`.

T-SQL Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
    [Id]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Category]      NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Quantity]      SMALLINT        NULL,
    [Price]         DECIMAL (18)    NULL,
    [Label]         NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Status]        NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [ImageData]     VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

What I want to do:

I want to delete the second row from database, but before that, it will check first and second row if there is same product name, if there is, then it will delete the last row (which is second row in this example), and update the quantity in the first row with what is the quantity in the second row. If first row have 10 quantity, and second row have 20 quantity, then the first row have 30 quantity, and the second row is gone (deleted)

Comment: is there unique identifier on two rows to identify uniquely? Better to include Table schema instead of Grid screenshot

Comment: Supply the SQL query you are using to generate this data.

Comment: No, it does not have @HaveNoDisplayName. It only have the primary key and unique key on Id, which is there by the time I create a new table.

Comment: For better solution, provide your table schema. You want to delete second row from database permanently or Just to combine result for display to user.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName: I want to delete the second row from database, but before that, it will check first and second row if there is same product name, if there is, then it will delete the last row (which is second row in this example), and update the quantity in the first row with what is the quantity in the second row. If first row have 10 quantity, and second row have 20 quantity, then the first row have 30 quantity, and the second row is gone (deleted).

Comment: @Stainn The SQL you provided is for the insert. Not the Select.

Comment: The table schema would help us answer this. Also - the query you have given is for inserting into the table - not selecting the data from the table.

Comment: Still no table schema!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update that will update the quantity of the first record with the sum of its quantity plus the quantities in any records with the same category and name that come after it, and then the delete statement that will delete those later records, while leaving your firstone intact:

```
update items i1
inner join items i2 on i1.category = i2.category and i1.name = i2.name
        and i1.id < i2.id
set i1.quantity = i1.quantity + i2.quantity

delete i1 from items i1
inner join items i2 on i1.id > i2.id and
    i1.category = i2.category and i1.name = i2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will group it for you. You are just summing the price and grouping by the rest of the columns.

```
SELECT 
    [Category], 
    [Name], 
    SUM([Quantity]), 
    [Price], 
    [Status], 
    [ImageData] 
FROM [Items] WHERE [Status] = @Active ORDER BY [Category] ASC
GROUP BY     
    [Category], 
    [Name], 
    [Price], 
    [Status], 
    [ImageData]
```

Ideally you should have a "ProductID" column in this table so that you can group by this instead of relying on the procuct Name being unique.

Comment: Hi sir @CathalMF, I already did on what you suggested and follow your code, but when I try to run the program which the table have like the image above, it says that the `Quantity` is out of range sir. And when I try to delete all of the columns in the table, and create a first column, it successful, but once I want to create the second column, it says the `Quantity` is out of range also sir.

Comment: @Stainn If you're getting those messages you must have some other validation in your code that requires them on separate lines. You will need to investigate this.